# Как записать тхт файл внутри dynamic web project

Tags: java

У меня есть dynamic web project. Мне нужно разместить внутри этого проекта текстовый файл и записывать туда информацию. Только проблема в том, в каком именно месте dynamic web project нужно создать файл, и какой путь к этому файлу должен быть. То есть чтобы не указывать полный путь к файлу например "C:/project/file.txt", а разместить файл внутри проекта и указывать краткий путь, который будет работать если перенести весь проект в другое место.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться относительным путём вашего проекта, определив его через загрузчик класа. [Пример](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html)